# Web Essentials for VS 2013 not appearing after installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I have successfully installed Web Essentials for VS 2013, but I am not able to find it in Tools->option. Am I missing something here? How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a restart of visual studio for it to appear in your Extensions window.